# Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install don't see sound card

Tags: 18.04, sound, hardware, soundcard

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 16.04 (format `/` and mount `/home`) alongside with Windows 10. Everything is Ok in Windows, but looks like Ubuntu just don't want to use soundcard.

I followed nearly every solution I could find but no success.

This is what I've got in settings.

[This is what I've got in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJKx4.png)

I only have sound in my system through HDMI port for now. I've connected speakerphones to my display, and eventually got sound this way, but it's a kind of weird.

System details.

```
~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO UART #0 (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago PRO [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] (rev 81)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM]
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

```
~$ inxi -A
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM]
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Logitech Webcam C270 driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-45-generic
```

```
:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 1 [U0x46d0x825    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x825
                      USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-0000:00:14.0-12, high speed
 2 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xdfe60000 irq 135
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
~$ groups $USER
max : max adm cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev lpadmin pulse sambashare rvm
```

```
:~$ cat /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
# Defaults for the speech-dispatcher initscript, from speech-dispatcher

# Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher
RUN=no
```

```
:~$ grep audio /etc/group
audio:x:29:max,pulse
```

What I've already tried without success
(with reboot on most of the steps):

```
pulseaudio --start

...

rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/

...

sudo alsa force-reload

...

sudo sudo /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
## then add at the bottom
options snd-hda-intel model=auto

...

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

...
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
pulseaudio -k
```

I also updated drivers for soundcard (following [this manual](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS)).

`alsamixer` only showing mixer interface with keys `alsamixer -c 1` and `alsamixer -c 2`, for the first device "This sound device does not have any playback controls." (I understand this is my webcam) and all channels unmuted for the second device and this one is HDA ATI HDMI.

I would appreciate any suggestions and help, because I have no idea what is going on and how to fix it.

**UPD1**

I've tried to load from Ubuntu Live USB first with 18.04, than with 16.04 Ubuntu and no sound in both cases.
Windows still functioning Ok.

**UPD2**

Following the very last posts from [this thread about sound problems](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=267963) I've updated BIOS for the motherboard.

Guess what?
Windows Ok, Ubuntu - no sound... will try Ubuntu Live USB versions.

**UPD3**

Check if Ubuntu Live USB 18.04 or 16.04 have sound after BIOS update. But no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all fruitless attempts for 2 days in a row, mentioned in the question... I am happy again!

I don't know how it works, but next order of actions, I believe, somehow helped me to get sound card working again in Ubuntu (all this methods I found in different sources, but for me only this particular compilation worked).

1. Update BIOS on my motherboard (still no sound in installed Ubuntu or any Ubuntu Live I've tried).
2. Some boots in Ubuntu and Windows.
3. Disable sound in BIOS / reboots / enable sound in BIOS (no sound in Ubuntu yet, but didn't check in Ubuntu Live).
4. Boot Windows and use it for some time with sound (watch movie).
5. Boot from Ubuntu Live USB and discover sound card detected by Ubuntu at last!
6. Reinstall Ubuntu from Live USB. Yep... sound is here!

"It's a kind of magic..." (c)

Good luck pals!